# List Comprehension with if statement and append - Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How can I write this in list comprehension?

```
letters= ['c', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b']
uniq=[]

for i in letters:
  if i not in uniq:
    uniq.append(i)
```

I've tried this but the return is a list with many 'None':

```
[uniq.append(i) for i in letters if i not in uniq]
```

Comment: So that is in `uniq`? It is usual to use the `for` loop as you have to do operations like this.

Comment: You cannot. You can't access the values you already added in he list comprehension until you end it. Just do `uniq = list(set(letters))`

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use a `set`. This contains only unique values:

```
unique=list(set(letters))
print(unique)
```

If you really would like to use a comprehension you can do this:

```
s = set()
[i for i in letters if not (i in s or s.add(i))]
```

This works, because s.add() returns `None`

Comment: Does this preserve the order?

Comment: When I run it on the OP's list, I get `['d', 'b', 'a', 'c']`, which is not the same order. This makes sense since sets are unordered collections.

Comment: You are right, I am wrong. It does NOT preserve order. `set`is unordered. But the comprehension does preserve the order if needed

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
uniq = [ch for ch in set(letters)]
```

Or:

```py
uniq = list(set(letters))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the unique elements in the `list`, then you can use `set` for list.

If give you the unique values in the list elements.

`set(letters)`

Answer (score -1):

It works fine.

```
[uniq.append(i) for i in letters if i not in uniq]
print(uniq)
```

Output:

```
['c', 'a', 'd', 'b']
```

The new list has Nones. But uniq is filled out correctly in the process.